# How exactly do you earn the Generalist badge?

Tags: support, tags, badges

As far as I can tell, for every other badge the description is clearly quantified in terms of the number of votes, posts, comments and so on you need to earn that badge. But for the Generalist badge, the description somewhat vaguely says "Active in many different tags." Is this actually the same as on Apple SE and Stackoverflow, on both of which the description says "Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags"?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the team flipped a switch at some point in time, because all of the *early* Stack Exchanges have the same description we do:

- Web Apps
- Gaming
- Webmasters
- Ask Ubuntu
- Seasoned Advice
- Game Dev
- Math
- Photo
- Stats
- Tex

All have the old "active in many different tags" description, from before the tag was actually implemented.  Every site launched from cstheory and afterward (programmers, Unix, Apple, and Wordpress) have the specific description.

It may actually be impossible to get the tag.  I'll see if I can nag one of the team into looking at this (if they haven't seen it already).

Comment: It is currently impossible for anyone on Seasoned Advice to earn this badge, even if the mechanics were identical to that of Stack Overflow. [As per the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/), the "top 40 tags" must have at least 200 questions each before the badge is even valid to be earned.